# how to call a web service callout from a method in a utility class

Tags: callout

DO anyone have the idea of how to call a web service callout from a method in a utility class . i mean web service response elements .

I have response class for a web service ....... but i dont want to use the web service response class directly ... i want a method to call the web service callout class so that i can make the required transformations necessary for the parameters .

Answer (score 1):

Here's documentation on Web Service Callouts (Google query = "web service invoke salesforce")

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts.htm

You invoke web services via the `WebService.invoke()` method.

Concerning the parameters of `WebService.invoke()`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392616/what-are-the-parameters-for-the-salesforce-webservicecallout-invoke-method

---

Please provide more details in your question if you need more assistance.